# Fade in Overlay with more pictures which are in one class

Tags: html, css, flexbox, hover

I am trying to resolve my problem with website.

I am using CSS Gap Space with FlexBox and the images are set in two rows of two images, so I would like to keep this view.

Now, I am trying to get into this pictures Fade in Overlay like this - [overlay](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_css_image_overlay_fade)

But when I set all the values, my code breaks.

```css
article {
  position: absolute;
  background-color:   linear-gradient(rgba(31, 38, 65, rgba(244, 244, 245, 0.7),0.7));
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.ciele {
  font-family: 'Inter',sans-serif;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: 220px;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 140%;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.ciele-popis{
  font-family: 'Tiemposfine' ,sans-serif;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 220px;
  font-size: 54px;
  line-height: 120%;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-right: 700px;
  flex: 1;
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 65px;
}

.image-box{
  height: 300px;
  position: static;
  margin-left: 220px;
  margin-right: 220px;
  object-fit: contain;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 120px;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h1 class="ciele">Náš cieľ</h1>
  <p class="ciele-popis">Zážitky, ktoré budujeme našími skúsenosťami.</p>

<div class="image-box">
  <img src="images/financne_sluzby.png" alt="" width="680px" height="465px">
  <img src="images/smiling-woman.jpeg" alt="" width="680px" height="465px"> 
  <img src="images/rodina.jpeg" alt="" width="680px" height="465px">
  <img src="images/biznis.jpeg" alt="" width="680px" height="465px"> 
</div>  



</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things causing your code to break, so instead of explaining every point, I've made corrections below.

1. See this helpful visual reference on [how to use Flexbox](https://flexbox.malven.co/).
2. Please also [review this on writing proper linear gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient()).

```css
article {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(31, 38, 65) 0%, rgba(244, 244, 245) 100%);
}

.ciele {
  font-family: 'Inter',sans-serif;
  margin-left: 220px;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 140%;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.ciele-popis{
  font-family: 'Tiemposfine' ,sans-serif;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 220px;
  font-size: 54px;
  line-height: 120%;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-right: 700px;
  flex: 1;
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 65px;
}

.image-box{
  place-content: center;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 120px;
}


img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.image-wrapper:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h1 class='ciele'>Náš cieľ</h1>
  <p class='ciele-popis'>Zážitky, ktoré budujeme našími skúsenosťami.</p>

  <section class='image-box'>
    <div class='image-wrapper'>
      <img src='https://loremflickr.com/500/360' alt=''>
      <div class='overlay'>
        <div class="text">Text Here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='image-wrapper'>
      <img src='https://loremflickr.com/500/360' alt=''>
      <div class='overlay'>
        <div class="text">Text Here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='image-wrapper'>
      <img src='https://loremflickr.com/500/360' alt=''>
      <div class='overlay'>
        <div class="text">Text Here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='image-wrapper'>
      <img src='https://loremflickr.com/500/360' alt=''>
      <div class='overlay'>
        <div class="text">Text Here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>  
</article>
```